# Merging ImageView to a single Bitmap image (Android)

Tags: android, bitmap, merge, imageview, viewgroup

I have more than one `ImageView` that I am adding dynamically into a layout class that extends `ViewGroup`, there is one for the background, and more than one other `ImageView` that are draggable on top of the background. I want to merge those `ImageView` into one single `Bitmap Image`, without disrupting the position of those dragged images.

Is there a way of merging different sized `ImageView`? Or merging the contents of a `ViewGroup`? Because I would later want to merge the image with `TextView` also...

Thank you for helping me :)

And let me know if you need more information.